# Can I convert the Google Style guide XML to PDF files?

Tags: pdf, xml

Google provides many programming documents; the source code is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/).

Can I convert these documents to PDF files? How can I do that? 
I googled, but haven't found any good way to do this.

I want to convert the [C++ guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read about XML and [XSL transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt). You should be able to just download the entire folder (i.e., with the `.xml`, `.css` and `.xsl` files), and then open the XML document with a browser.

All major web browsers should be able to transform the XML using the XSL and CSS files provided, into a nice looking page. I've found Chrome to be buggy with local XML files, but opening the style guide XML in the Google Code repository browser (in raw mode) worked as well.

You can then print from your browser to PDF, using a PDF generator of your choice.